# Static Library header attempting to use Source instead of Library

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, static-libraries

So in VS 2012, I've created a static library that i want to use in another project. When I try to use the library, I get errors trying to compile using the source files

```
"fatal error C1083: Cannot open source file: '<file used in library>.cpp':
    No such file or directory
```

I feel like I'm missing something simple to make it work the way I want but I can't wrap my head around the way to do it.

Also, this may be irrelevant, but is there any automated way to combine headers to a single .h file to use for a library?

Comment: Are you doing something weird like `#include [file].cpp`?

Comment: Nothing of the sort @Wug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're adding .cpp files from the library to your project. That's not the way to use a static library, instead add the library's .lib file (with the full path) in **Configuration Properties | Linker | Input | Additional Dependencies**, and then just add #include directives in your project's files to include any headers from the library you need to use.

Comment: Sadly that was already done and does not seem to be the problem (even when I put the full path)

Comment: Well, you have to be referencing **some** .cpp file from the library in **some** way to get the error you describe.

Comment: Just did a search and I nowhere reference any .cpp files. I of course use .cpp to create the library but i don't use them (or reference them) anywhere for the project I'm using the library in

Comment: Never mind, I found the issue. I DID have residual references to the source files even though I removed the files but never cleared them out of the project. Thanks for all the help.